# Почему не может прочитать картинку?

Tags: opencv

У меня появилась ошибка "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'". В чём заключается ошибка и как её исправить? Вот код:

```
import cv2 as cv
from numpy import *

haystack_img = cv.imread('images/original.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_img = cv.imread('images/pruning.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
waitKey()
```

Вот новый код:

```
import cv2 as cv
from numpy import *

haystack_img = cv.imread('images/original.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_img = cv.imread('images/pruning.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

haystack_img.astype(np.float32)
needle_img.astype(np.uint8)

result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
waitKey()
```

Вот так?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

haystack_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41 (1).jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

if len(img.shape) == 3:
    img.shape[-1]

haystack_img.astype(np.float32)
needle_img.astype(np.float32)





result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138369/discussion-on-question-by-il16ya-----).

Comment: Попробуйте уберить cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED.

Comment: Всё равно появляется